# Evaluate the triple integral over the region W using the appropriate change of variables/coordinate

Tags: calculus, integration

> Evaluate $$\iiint_W \left( x^2 + y^2 + z^2 \right)^{1/2}\, dx\, dy\,dz$$ given that $$W=\{ (x,y,z)\in\mathbb{R}^3\mid x^2+y^2+z^2\leq x\}$$

I know that the region is a sphere of radius $1/2$ and centered at $(1/2,0,0)$, and I tried to use cylindrical coordinates, but obviously I couldn't solve the integral. So, the way I think it will work is using spherical coordinates. The problem is that I don't know how the variables are related.

Comment: If you don't know how the variables $x,y,z$ are related to $r,\theta,\phi$ this link might help: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SphericalCoordinates.html

Comment: I know how to use the spherical coordinates, but I don't understand how to use in this case because it's out of the origin. Then, I don't know how I can find the limits of integration suitable to this integral and region.

Comment: Ahhh, yes I see. Perhaps you could use $u$ substitution to shift the region back to be centered around the origin. It shouldn't change the region's volume if you do it correctly.

Comment: Yes, I tried that. The problem is that the integral becames a mess because of the square root. At least with what I did.

Comment: Then I tried to think a way relating the variables, for example, I projected the sphere into the xy-plane, then changed x and y to the spherical coordinates. With that I found the r(θ,ϕ). So, I had 0<θ<pi and 0<r<r(θ,ϕ). But I didn't find ϕ(θ), because I cannot assume that θ and ϕ are independent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use spherical coordinates with the positive x-axis as the pole. Let $r$ be the distance from the origin, $\phi$ be the (polar) angle from the positive x-axis, and $\theta$ be the (azumithal) angle in the yz-plane (note that the integral will be symmetric in $\theta$) .Our function to integrate is thus simply $r$. The region of integration is a sphere of radius $\frac 12$ whose center is at $x=\frac 12$ on the x-axis. We can write the integral using the volume differential $dV=r^2\sin(\phi)\ d\phi\ d\theta\ dr$.

$$I=\int_0^1\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^{\phi_0(r)}r^3\sin(\phi)\ d\phi\ d\theta\ dr$$

Where $\phi_0(r)$ is the  $\phi$ coordinate of the boundary of the sphere for fixed $r$. We can find it using the law of cosines, drawing a triangle whose vertices are the origin, the center of the sphere, and a point on the surface of the sphere a distance $r$ from the origin.

[image]

$$\left(\frac 12\right)^2=r^2+\left(\frac 12\right)^2-2r\left(\frac 12\right)\cos(\phi_0(r))$$

$$\phi_0(r)=\arccos(r)$$

Separating the integral:

$$I=2\pi\int_0^1r^3dr\int_0^{\arccos(r)}\sin(\phi)d\phi$$

From here, the calculus is reasonably straightforward.

$$I=2\pi\int_0^1r^3[-\cos(\phi)]_{\phi=0}^{\phi=\arccos(r)}dr$$

$$I=2\pi\int_0^1r^3\left[1-r\right]dr$$

$$I=2\pi\int_0^1\left[r^3-r^4\right]dr$$

$$I=2\pi\left[\frac 14r^4-\frac 15r^5\right]_{r=0}^{r=1}$$

$$I=\frac \pi{10}$$

Comment: Thanks! I did it yesterday, but your way is a little different. What I did was $0<θ<π$, $0<ϕ<π$, $0<r<cos(θ)*sin(ϕ)$.